# <audio> em div oculta

Tags: jquery

tenho uma div com display:none e nessa div tem um audio, porém se eu usar o autoplay, mesmo a div oculta, o audio fica tocando, gostaria que tocasse o audio somente quando a div estiver aparecendo. Podem me ajudar?

```
<div class="fig1"></div>

.fig1{display:none}
.evnt1{display:block}

<script>$('.fig1').click(function(){
$('.fig1').show('slow');});
</script>
```

Comment: é pra parar de tocar quando a div terminar de aparecer?

Comment: é para tocar somente qdo a div aparecer

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter o valor do dsplay de  sua div com o código abaixo em seguida utilize um if para determinar a ação sobre o aúdio.

```
var display = $('.fig1').css('display');
var som =$(soundobj);
if(display == 'none'){
   som.stop();
   // para o audio.
}else som.play();
```

Não fiz conferências sobre o código adapte a suas necessidades 
Boa sorte!

Comment: Não deu certo! Se eu usar autoplay fica direto, se não usar, não toca. Uso o Click para retirar o display=none, mas o audio não segue o none.

Comment: Poste o exemplo completo para correção !

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar uma `id` no seu audio e fazer conforme segue:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="some_audio.mp3"></a>
<div class="fig1"></div>

.fig1{display:none}
.evnt1{display:block}

<script>$('.fig1').click(function(){
    $('.fig1').show('slow', function(){
        document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
    });});
</script>
```

Comment: Corretíssimo também, mas pelo que eu percebi ele usa jquery!

Comment: De acordo com a documentação do método `show` do jQuery, disponível em http://api.jquery.com/show/ , ele pode receber uma função callback que vai ser disparada assim que a animação é terminada. O que eu fiz foi enviar essa função e, dentro dela, dar o play(). Espero que tenha resolvido seu problema